# GCC no vectorization output?

Tags: c++, gcc, vectorization, pragma

I am trying to vectorize a loop using ivdep but I'm not getting any output. I looked at the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options) and used the flags mentioned there. This is my code:

```
int main()
{
int a[100], b[100];
int size = 100;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      a[i] = 5; 

#pragma GCC ivdep
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
      b[i] = a[i] + i;
}
```

How I compile it:

```
g++ vectest.c -O2 -fopt-info-all -fopt-info-missed-all -o vectest
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the -g flag to make the GNU Debugger work.
Compile it this way:

```
g++ vectest.c -O2 -g -fopt-info-all -fopt-info-missed-all -o vectest
```

Comment: If isn't that you wanted as a answer, let me know.

Comment: So I really misunderstood what you wanted there. Try to explain more about "what this output must be", please

Comment: I just want it to tell me if the loop was vectorized or not. This is just a test program. I have a very large parallel application and I'm not getting any speed ups when I use #pragmas, and I cannot debug because I don't get any debugging vectorization output. Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29292944/2942145) @Barretxx

Comment: Ah... I see it now. So, if you want to see if your program uses the parallelism in the best way it can use, so compile it without any optimization (-O0 flag). Then you will be able to see the sequential code running step by step. You think this way it will output what you want @Mo

Comment: Sorry, misspelled you username @Moody *

Comment: I got the output I need by using this: `g++ vectest.c -O3 -fopt-info-all -fopt-info-all-missed -o vectest` . I was using 'missed-all' instead of 'all-missed'. But now I have another problem. This only works if I specify `O3`, regardless of `ivdep`. Why won't `ivdep` work by itself? @Barretxx