# Is it useful to vectorize code if g++ already optimizes for this?

Tags: c++, g++, vectorization

Since g++ already optimizes for loop vectorization with the O3 flag: [How to vectorize my loop with g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292818/how-to-vectorize-my-loop-with-g)

Is it useful at all I try to vectorize my C++ code?

Comment: no, write clean and simple code and do not try to outsmart your compiler :)

Comment: I think you are asking if it is useful for you to put in extra work to *try* to optimize your code into a less-readable mess, instead of letting the compiler reliably perform the same -- or sometimes better -- optimizations for you. Is that the gist of your question?

Comment: @JaMiT Yes, I'm wondering if it will always optimize it the same or better